# SEO google link tracking

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo, googlebot

I'm looking into an issue on a site that I manage.

Whats happening is that when you look at the cached version of the site (the text version) from Google it is not showing some of the child navigation links.

I'm not quite sure how google bots work to find these links but I cant see anything wrong with my markup.

Here is a snippet of code that i use for the navigation:

```
 <div id="tabsPanel">
    <ul>
        <li class="home" id="home_item">
            <a href="/" class="current">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="type" id="shopbystyle_item">
            <a href="#" class="item parent">Style</a>
            <ul id="menucontainer" class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                <li class="style1" id="contemporary_item">
                    <a href="/modern" class="item">
                    Modern
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="traditional" id="traditional_item">
                    <a href="/traditional" class="item">
                    Traditional
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="type" id="shopbycolor_item">
            <a href="#" class="item parent">Color</a>
            <ul id="menucontainer" class="submenu" style="display: none;">
                <li class="style1" id="blue_item">
                    <a href="/blue" class="item">
                    Blue
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="traditional" id="red_item">
                    <a href="/red" class="item">
                    Red
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The "Home" and "Style" links are picked up by Google however the "Modern" and "Traditional" links are not.

I use JavaScript to show/hide the sub menu but surely this shouldn't cause Google to not pick up those links? On other sites I have seen Google pick up links on navigation items that are shown using JavaScript.

Could it have something to do with the fact that both of my submenu ul elements have the same ID?

My question is why is Google only seeing the parent links and not the child links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using absolute URL's for the sub menu items worked. Not sure why this would be but i changed the following:

From this:

```
<li class="style1" id="contemporary_item">
    <a href="/modern" class="item">
        Modern
    </a>
</li>
```

**To this:**

```
<li class="style1" id="contemporary_item">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/modern" class="item">
        Modern
    </a>
</li>
```